# InMemoryRandomAccessStream incorrect(?) behavior

Tags: c#, stream, windows-runtime

I have 2 methods with identical functionality:

```
private static async Task<IRandomAccessStream> _DownloadImage(string url)
{
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    var httpStream = await http.GetStreamAsync(url);
    var memStream = new MemoryStream();
    await httpStream.CopyToAsync(memStream);
    memStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    return memStream.AsRandomAccessStream();
}
```

and

```
private static async Task<IRandomAccessStream> _DownloadImage2(string url)
{
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    var httpStream = await http.GetStreamAsync(url);
    var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    await httpStream.CopyToAsync(stream.AsStreamForWrite());
    stream.Seek(0);
    return stream;
}
```

The problem is that for some URLs the second version gives a zero-length `stream`. Is it a bug or am I missing something?
The url for which the first version gives a normal stream with picture while the second one is empty: `http://icdn.lenta.ru/images/2014/09/17/10/20140917102331786/pic_ffa73ea27023b3e69b6cef4d068c0499.jpg`

**UPD:**

I've found that files which have size below 16384 are at risk. I found this 16384 value at the [AsStreamForWrite](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh582117(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation. 
@Kiewic, also proposed a workaround. Still I'd like to know why it doesn't work as is.

**UPD2:**
Created a [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/977380#tabs) in Connect.

Comment: The language projection for AsStreamForWrite() is quite ugly.  WinRT streams are not a good match for .NET streams so a great deal of code is necessary to paper over the differences.  Lots of special cases to deal with different kind of streams, there's also code that hides the differences in earlier Phone releases.  Too many moving parts, a bug is a strong possibility.  You shouldn't write code like this in the first place, using BitmapSource.SetSourceAsync() is pretty important to avoid chewing up lots of memory.  Best to stick with code that works :)

Comment: @HansPassant, I can't create BitmapImage in non-UI thread.

Comment: Just believe: you don't need an answer. Just do everything you can to avoid using all those helpers to convert Windows Runtime types to .NET classes. If you want to know why, just read [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/37ac0ed7-1884-4251-9914-07fae6467b98/mediastreamsource-not-working-properly-in-windows-phone-81) starting from the end. You will avoid a whole bunch of problems including random OutOfMemoryExceptions if you'll just give up converting Windows Runtime to .NET.

Comment: @Alovchin, thanks for the link. I'll read it.

Answer (score 1):

It works when you keep the `Stream` in a variable, try:

```
// using System.Net.Http;

private static async Task<IRandomAccessStream> _DownloadImage2(string url)
{
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    var httpStream = await http.GetStreamAsync(url);
    var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();

    Stream streamForWrite = stream.AsStreamForWrite();
    await httpStream.CopyToAsync(streamForWrite);

    stream.Seek(0);
    Debug.WriteLine("Length: " + streamForWrite.Length);
    Debug.WriteLine("Size: " + stream.Size);

    return stream;
}
```

Comment: This helps, indeed. But it doesn't answer why the basic version doesn't work. Please, look at the updated post